# Firebase - Return Boolean for Anonymous User

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using Firebase. I'm trying to figure out how can I get a Boolean for Anonymous User?

I know I can do a completion block, but I wanted to avoid being inside of a block. I was think of something like this `FirAuth.isAnonymous`. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way ..

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
    print(user.anonymous)
    self.signedIn(user)
}
```

Comment: great idea i did not think of that